# How can I create a scrollable list in my windows 8 app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I want to present a list. The list contains strings of text, but as it is now (I'm using ListView) I cant get to the bottom of the list. I pops back up and gets hard to drag down after some elements.

Maybe I'm not using the right control?

Comment: Have you tried [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780616.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780616.aspx). If there are more elements than ListBox´s size, there will appear a scrollBar.

[More informations about ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868196.aspx)